# Ruby : Converting String to a Method Call

Tags: ruby, excel

I am new to Ruby. I'm trying to convert a string to a method call in
Ruby. I intend to store all my function calls in an Excel Worksheet and
use the extracted strings to make the actual method call. But I am not
able to convert the string obtained from the excel and use it as a
function call. I read somewhere that the Send() method helps convert
strings to method calls. But I am not able to use it correctly. For the
code mentioned below I obtain a "in `<top (required)>': undefined method`
Execute_Statement(5)' for main:Object (NoMethodError)"

---

```
 begin
    def Execute_Statement(var1)
    puts("Hello",var1)
    end
 end

x='Execute_Statement(5)' #This would be fed from the Excel Worksheet

send(x)
```

---

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Not a good practice, but you can do `eval(x)`

Answer (score 1):

You can either adopt the bad practice, i.e. Just do `eval(x)`. If don't want to adopt it, do some more work as below :

```
def Execute_Statement(var1)
  puts("Hello",var1)
end
s = "Execute_Statement(5)" # I hope this is coming from your excel cell.
method_name,number = s[/.*(?=\()/],s[/\d+/]
send(method_name,number.to_i)
```

Remove the `begin..end` block, it is not needed for your case.

Comment: Thank you Arup. I decided to provide the function name in the first column of the excel and the parameters in the remaining columns of that row. The problem I am facing currently is that I will be sending multiple functions(having varying number of parameters) in the first column of my excel and I need my code to pick these parameters and send these along with the function name in the Send method. Could you suggest an approach for this need ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be passing your parameter as part of the send call. Also the method name needs to be a symbol. In other words define the function name as a symbol and define your parameter as a separate variable, then call `send` like so:

```
def Execute_Statement(var1)
  puts("Hello",var1)
end

method_name = 'Execute_Statement'.to_sym
parameter = 5

send(method_name,parameter)
```

As commenter above says this does not seem like a great idea.